# Are my plans for adding a 240 volt circuit reasonable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v

I was hoping I could run this by someone. I've done other basic homeowner electric work like adding 120 breakers and outlets. From reading online, adding a single 240 volt circuit next to my breaker box doesn't seem that more difficult than what I've done before.

---

Digiboil 65L : 20 amps 3500 watts. Has a nema 6-30h plug. 6-30h outlets are only 30amps though.

22 ft from circuit breaker.

So I went with a 30 amp 2-pole breaker (square D and HOM like my other breakers) and nm-b 10-2 wire. Will use the neutral white wire as the second hot (and label it red).

Does all this sound good? Should the breaker be gfci protected? I don't believe I need a neutral.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 3):

The sales info I looked at showed it with a 3 wire plug so it should be ok. Some electronic controlled devices require a neutral and then a 4 wire would be needed but it looks to be straight 240 so your plan should work.  As far as GFCI code specifies 15 & 20 amp circuits so it would not be required but gfci’s around liquid are a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, Ed. I know that 220 is old-school terminology for 240, but it's confusing to laypeople and needs to die. :)

Comment: Ok, cool. Thanks!! Why is gfci required for 15 and 20 but not 30 amps?

Comment: @Fun4stuff - Actually it depends on what the receptacle is being used for. For example pool equipment Article 680 will require it to be protected. So you need to identify what equipment you will use on it and go to the corresponding  Article in chapter 6 and check to see if you need protection. I would suggest you do protect it because it is in a damp location and it would just make its use more safe. What's wrong with that.

Comment: @isherwood, the sales info listed it as 220 , I usually do state 240 but if a question says 220 I try to use both or stay with what they asked to not confuse them.

Comment: Yeah, i ordered the gfci breaker. Might as well play it safe. Thank you all!

Comment: @Fun4stuff  Please say you didn't order it at Amazon or Ebay.

Comment: For protection issues you may need to install the wire in a raceway, and if using a raceway it would be better to get just 30 feet of black, red, and green #10 THHN/THWN wire rather than sizing the conduit for NM, and for proper wire color.

Comment: I ordered from homedepot. They didn't have it in stock.

Comment: The circuit is in an unfinished area of my basement. No drywall. Other wires are run through the rafters.  I was going to run in 3-4 feet of conduit (i think 0.5") to the ceiling and then through the rafters along the other wire. Is this ok?

Comment: 220 will never die.  After Tesla won the war of the currents and electricity became scalable, it was marketed to the proletariat. At the time, electricity actually was 110/220V.  (Edison having done two bumps from the nice, round 100/200V for capacity reasons).  So it's like Xerox or Jell-o.

Comment: @fun4stuff below 8’ or going up the wall protection is needed once you are in the ceiling it will be ok with your nmb wire, I know you said you are pulling 10-2  in but I might suggest 10-3 if you have not purchased the wire, a bit more expensive but if you want to do different things in the future spending a couple of extra dollars opens up more options.

Comment: @Ed Beal Yeah, I'm going to exchange 10-2 for 10-3 and just do it right. Is 1/2" pvc conduit ok? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: No you will need 3/4 to get that in the pipe. it’s only 1 stick make life easier yet and use 1” . I haven’t run the numbers on fill but know 1/2 is two small.

Comment: One last question I hope. I was looking at the gfci breaker I ordered. It has plugs for 2 hots and one neutral and then has a curly white neutral wire coming off it. I don't need a neutral wire for my 6-30h outlet. Do I just cap the neutrals off at breaker and outlet? Plug the Neutral coming from the 10-3 wire into the breaker and then plug neutral from breaker into neutral bar?  Here is the breaker: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-30-Amp-2-Pole-GFCI-Circuit-Breaker-Clear-Packaging-HOM230GFIC/204355352

Comment: Didn’t quite word that right and phone is not letting me edit it. I meant to say: do i just cap of neutral wires on the 10-3 wire at both and run the curly neutral from HF i breaker to neutral bar?

Comment: Yes I usually put a wire nut on the white since you don’t need it. 
With a single wire I usually put tape on the wirenut to help hold it in place but even a piece of tape over the end of this will be fine, it would not hurt to land the wire on your neutral buss in the panel.